# Toast aparece con fondo y texto en blanco una vez subido a producción

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, sweetalert2

Estoy desarrollando un formulario para editar los datos de un equipo: la función toma los datos, valida que no estén vacíos y lanza un Sweet Alert de confirmación para subir los datos y enseguida los toast.
Cabe resaltar que es la primera vez que manejo imágenes y no sé si estoy haciendo bien el proceso de capturar la imagen así que les agradecería que me orientaran si estoy bien, la estoy regando o si hay un mejor método de hacerlo.

Resulta que he probado la librería de toastr en mi servidor local antes de agregar el componente a producción y me sale bien como debe de ser y con las opciones que le configuré, pero una vez que aplico el código a mi documento en producción, el toast aparece en blanco, tanto texto como fondo e íconos.

Ya revisé que estuvieran bien referenciadas las librerías tanto en css como el js, el jquery se carga primero y las opciones de toastr están definidas al inicio del js.
Aún así he intentado quitarlas y darle las opciones como parámetro mientras uso la función del toastr.
Cabe decir que sí respeta las opciones que le doy y el texto que le digo que muestre.

Como pueden ver, la consola sale sin errores, pero el toastr se muestra en blanco completamente, apenas se distingue el texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
      $(document).ready(function() { 
      toastr.options = {
            "positionClass": "toast-bottom-left",
            "progressBar" : true,
            "preventeDuplicates": true,
            "timeOut": 2500,
            "extendedTimeOut": 1200,
            "showEasing": "swing",
              "hideEasing": "linear",
              "showMethod": "slideDown",
              "hideMethod": "slideUp"
        }

    $(document).on("click", "#btnEditar", function(){               
            opcion = 2;//editar
            var Nombre = $("#iNombre").val();
            var Tipo = $("#mTipo").val();
            var CodigoS = $("#iNserie").val();
            var Fecha = $("#iFechaCompra").val();
            let Foto = new FormData($("#editForm")[0]);
            var Descripcion = $("#iDesc").val();
            var ver = $("#iModelo").val();

            if (ver!="Seleccione uno" && Nombre != "" && Tipo != "" && CodigoS != "" && Descripcion != "" && ver != "") {
                       
            swal({
                title:"Actualizar Mobiliario",
                text: "¿Esta seguro de actualizar el equipo con los siguientes datos? "+"\n\nNombre: "+Nombre +"\nDescripcion: "+Descripcion+ "\nTipo: " + Tipo + "\nNo. Serie: " + CodigoS +
                " \nFecha de compra: " + Fecha + "\nVersion:" + ver,
                icon: "warning",
                buttons: true,
                dangerMode: true  
            }).then((isUpdate)=>{
                        if (isUpdate) { 
                                $.ajax({
                                    url:"DataBaseConector/equipos.php",
                                    type:"post",
                                    datatype:"json",
                                    processData: false,
                                    data: {opcion:opcion, 
                                            Nombre: Nombre,
                                            Tipo: Tipo,
                                            CodigoS: CodigoS,
                                            Descripcion: Descripcion,
                                            Fecha:Fecha,
                                            Foto: Foto,
                                            Version: Version},
                                            success: function () {
                                                toastr.success("Los datos se actualizaron con exito","Mobiliario actualizado");                                        
                                            }, error: function () {
                                                console.log("error con el envio del formulario")
                                            }
                                });
                        }
                        else{
                            toastr.error("Los datos no se actualizaron", "Operacion cancelada");
                           
                        }
            }); // fin promesa
        } else{
           /*  toastr.error("Complete todos los campos", "Hay espacios vacios"); */
        }toastr.error("Complete todos los campos", "Hay espacios vacios", "Title", {
            "timeOut": "0",
            "extendedTImeout": "0"
                });
               
           });// fin funcion
        
        });// fin $(document).ready();
```

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="es">

    <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
      <title>Mobiliario</title>
      
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- CSS personalizado -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      <!--datables CSS básico-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/datatables/datatables.min.css" />
      <!--datables estilo bootstrap 4 CSS-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/datatables/DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--alertify-->
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/alertify/css/alertify.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/alertify/css/alertify.css" /> -->

      <!-- Toastr CSS-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/toastr/toastr.min.css">

    </head>

    <body>
      
       <!-- Al final del documento -->
       
      <script src="assets/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="assets/popper/popper.min.js"></script> -->
      <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <!-- datatables JS -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="mainMobiliario.js"></script>
     >
        <!-- Toastr -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>

      <!--sweet alert-->
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: ¿Ese `script` antes de `<!doctype html>` es porque intentaste agregar un snippet en ediciones anteriores de la pregunta? ¿Ese `>` antes de referenciar a _toastr_ está en tu código o solo es un error de tipeo aquí?

Comment: esto es tipico de choque de clases css y paquetes, estas seguro que borraste la cache del navegador, revisa bien que no estes cargando los datos dede la cache pues eso suele suceder cuando el navegador no esta cargando todo el proyecto